# How to Give div ID image with Back link attached?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to give a div id an image with a back link centered to the left of 850 px. On the same Line I need a Div Id centered in that same 850px line with text. Any help is appreciated

Here is my CSS

```
        #container3 > div {
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#FFFF00;
    font-size:18;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:Normal;
    width:850px;

}
    #BackLink {
    position:relative;
    background-image: url(../Images/Back-ButtonB.png);
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:80;
    height="18;

}
    #ObjectName {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;

}
```

And here are the div ids

```
 <div id="container3">
<div id="BackLink"><a href=[Backlink]></a></div><div id="ObjectName">[ObjectName]</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have just put this jsfiddle together to illustrate the use of absolute positioning and text align.  position:relative is set on your parent div (container3). Backlink is absolutely positioned in the top left and objectname has text align: centre so that the text is centered across the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/GXMbL/1/

```
<div id="container3">
  <div id="BackLink">
    <a href=[BackLink]>
      <!-- <img border="0" src="../Images/Back-ButtonB.gif" width="80" height="18"> -->
        Backlink        
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="ObjectName">[ObjectName]</div>
</div>
```

and the css (this will need refining for your purposes but it has the basics of what you need)

```
#container3{
    width:450px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#999999;
}
#BackLink{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#ObjectName{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much hit that on the nose!

Answer (score 1):

The underlining and link problems are because you aren't closing your `<a>` with the `</a>`.

Html should be:

```
<div id="container3">
  <div id="BackLink">
    <a href=[BackLink]>
      <img border="0" src="../Images/Back-ButtonB.gif" width="80" height="18">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="ObjectName">[ObjectName]</div>
</div>
```

This may or may not solve your layout issues but it is definitely the answer to the question about the underlining

Wing

Comment: No I figured the underlining out I just need a backlink with an image of an arrow to the left then object name centered

Comment: How do I give a div id an image with a backlink attached to it using css?

Comment: Do you know about absolute positioning.  You can use this to position child divs at an exact location with the parent. If your 850px container is not going to change size then this will work.